# What needs changing to make a Fortran 90 Subroutine "PURE"?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I've defined a code module (a Fortran F90 file) and supplied it with these two subroutines:

```
pure Subroutine XRotation (x, y, z, Xrot, xp, yp, zp)
! Rotate about X-axis through the angle Xrot

real*4, INTENT(IN) :: x, y, z, xrot
real*4, INTENT(OUT) :: xp, yp, zp
real*4 xrad

Xrad = Xrot * 3.141592627 / 180 ! Convert to radians
yp = y * COS(Xrad) + z * SIN(Xrad)
xp = x
zp = z * COS(Xrad) - y * SIN(Xrad)


END


Pure Subroutine DummyDummy()

Call XRotation(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

End Subroutine
```

The compiler (Intel Fortran 12, targeting 32-bit Windows, for whatever that's worth) returns a single error message:

> error #7137: Any procedure referenced in a PURE procedure, including
>   one referenced via a defined operation or assignment, must be
>   explicitly declared PURE.   [XROTATION]

I'm a little bit stumped. How can I change this code so that the PURE Subroutine "DummyDummy" compiles?

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know much about fortran 90 (back in my day etc etc) but if you place that in a module it works.  i get the impression that modules are needed for various "modern" fortran features.

anyway, someone smarter (or younger?) than me can explain, but that should help you continue.

```
module foo
  implicit none
contains

  pure Subroutine XRotation (x, y, z, Xrot, xp, yp, zp)
  ....

end module foo
```

ah, here's an explanation (see the answers) - [Writing and calling pure subroutines in Fortran 90 using gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498973/writing-and-calling-pure-subroutines-in-fortran-90-using-gfortran)

ps i also get a type warning as you're passing in integers to float arguments.